# How to manipulate the back button of a browser

Tags: javascript, php, browser, back

What I am trying to do is to change the link of the back button of a browser. For example I want to go 2 pages behind, not only one.

Comment: php has no "Backbutton" ....

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Any browser has a back button. That's what I am trying ti manipulate.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate the history with JavaScript [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). I'm not sure that it's possible to actually make "Back" button go two pages back, though, but the API is pretty flexible so you might be able to work around your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to manipulate the back button as the people above have said. What i did, was to use some javascript after my job was done.
This is my code in php:

```
print "<script>window.history.go(-2); </script>";
```

Simple but it does its job!

Comment: Interesting, it seems to work automatically for me on form submittal, its not what I was looking for but it actually solves my problem better than what I was looking for! =)